# Snap7 writing to a S7-1200 PLC

Tags: c++-cli, plc, s7-1200, siemens

I'm trying to write something to my Siemens [PLC](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmable_logic_controller) with a C++/CLI application.

Reading is ok (except the first time it reads it gives odd values).

But writing is doing something completely different then what I want.

below you can find the code:

```
    private: void WriteSiemensDB()
    {
        byte* buffer;

        if (ConnectToSiemensPLC()) //Check if you are connected to PLC
        {
        String^ msg;
        int DBNumber = 2;
        bool NDR;
                                                       
        //Getting the values 1 time so buffer has a value
        buffer = sPLC->ReadDB(DBNumber);
        
        //give variables a value to write it to the PLC
        NDR = true;
        
        sPLC->SetBitAt(buffer, 0, 0, NDR); //Convert a bool to a bit
    
        msg = sPLC->WriteDB(DBNumber, buffer); //write to the Datablock in Siemens

        MessageBox::Show(msg); //Show if it worked or not
    }
}
```

The sPLC->SetBitAt method:

```
void SiemensPLC::SetBitAt(byte buffer[], int Pos, int Bit, bool Value)
{
    byte Mask[] = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80 };
    if (Bit < 0) Bit = 0;
    if (Bit > 7) Bit = 7;

    if (Value)
    {
        buffer[Pos] = (byte)(buffer[Pos] | Mask[Bit]);
    }
    else
    {
        buffer[Pos] = (byte)(buffer[Pos] & ~Mask[Bit]);
    }
}
```

WriteDB method:

```
System::String^ SiemensPLC::WriteDB(int DBnumber, byte buffer[])
{
    int Result;
    String^ msg;
    Result = MyClient->DBWrite(DBnumber, 0, 80, buffer);

    if (Result == 0)
    {
        msg = "Gelukt!"; //success
    }
    else
    {
        msg = "Mislukt, error:" + Result; //failed
    }
    return msg;
}
```

I actually get the message "Gelukt", but it still writes the rwong values. So something goes wrong with filling my `buffer`. Am I doing something wrong in with the buffer?

In C# I have the same kind of application except the buffer is a `byte buffer[];`

My questions are:

- Whats the difference between a `byte* buffer;`in C++ and a `byte buffer[];` in C#?
- When I mouse over on my buffer when I'm debugging, it says `buffer* = 0 ''`. Does that mean it's empty? if so, why does it still send random numbers to my PLC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Whats the difference between a `byte* buffer;`in C++ and a `byte buffer[];` in C#?

Assuming you have `typedef unsigned char byte;`:

In C++/CLI, `byte* buffer;` declares a `buffer` variable which is a pointer to a `byte`. In C# you write it as: `byte* buffer;` in an `unsafe` context. The syntax is the same.

In C#, `byte[] buffer;` declares a `buffer` variable which is a managed array of `byte` values. The C++/CLI syntax for this is `array<byte> buffer;`.

Note that `byte buffer[N];` is C++ syntax for a native array, which is *not* the same thing. That one can decay to a `byte*` pointer.

Looks like your code uses a native memory buffer, but there's no way to tell that for sure without the source of `ReadDB`.

> When I mouse over on my buffer when I'm debugging, it says `buffer* = 0 ''`. Does that mean it's empty? if so, why does it still send random numbers to my PLC?

It means the first byte in your buffer is `0`. If your buffer is supposed to contain C string data, it means it contains the empty string.

> Am I doing something wrong in with the buffer?

Most probably. But I can't say exactly what's wrong, because you didn't post the source of `ReadDB`.

There are a couple of red flags though:

- What's the buffer size? Your code doesn't know what `ReadDB` returns, so how are you supposed to ensure you're not overflowing it?
- Who's the owner of the buffer, meaning: who's supposed to free it? It *presumably* lives on the heap, so your code is leaking memory. If it lives on `ReadDB`'s stack you have a memory corruption issue. Either way, this code is wrong.

Comment: Ye I've noticed I had to change my buffer to an array, I've done this and it's solved now. Thanks for the info! :)